# Convert the wordpress YouTube tag to an object embed

Tags: regex, wordpress, youtube

If a few of you are unfamiliar with Wordpress's YouTub tag, it looks like this

```
[youtube=http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ooCLnrmIRFo&feature=related]
```

I am not very good with regular expressions, and all I have found out how to do is get from everything in between "[youtube=" and "]" using the following, but i need the value of "v".

```
(\[youtube=)(.+)(\])
```

Your help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
\[youtube=http://[^\]]+v=([\w-]+)[^\]]*\]
```

However, it would be better to just extract the URL and then use some validation on it, and finally pass it to parse_url and parse_str($url['query'], $blah) => $blah['v'] will have the v param then.

Comment: I like your suggestion and your regex... now i am torn ;)